# why are my non www https url not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I created a static s3 bucket site that works.  I created a certificate for:

- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

with additional names:

- *.example.com
- example.com

In my DNS I successfully attached all 2 certificates.  Yes, all 2 because the wildcard and the blank subdomain were the same CNAME values.

In the DNS I have [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) CNAME going to the cloudfront url.

I figured maybe this was the issue and I should use no www and also try a wildcard, but both simply didn't work and nothing loaded.

I then created a CloudFront and attached the certificate to it with Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)

- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- *.example.com
- example.com

In CloudFront my Viewer Protocol Policy is REDIRECT TO HTTPS

**The behavior:**

- https://www.example.com works
- http://www.example.com works (redirects to https://www.example.com)
- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) works (redirects to https://www.example.com)
- example.com works (redirects to https://www.example.com)
- https://example.com breaks with a (fail) and then auto attempts with (failed)net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
- http://example.com breaks with a (fail)

One other thing is, I do have a separate certificate for a separate website on a subdomain sub.example.com.  Would this possibly affect it?

Is there anything that stands out that would be doing this?

Comment: You wrote "www.example.com CNAME going to the cloudfront url."? What about `example.com`? Where does it point to?

Comment: When I try to add the example.com or *.example.com to the same cloudfront url, it won't let me enter it in saying invalid entry

Comment: I did attempt to remove the www.domain.com cname for the cloudfront url and use a wildcard, but it wouldn't load at all

Comment: Usually you would have to CNAMES. www.example.com->CF and example.com -> CF. Have you tried that?

Comment: Its not letting me do both? I'm on name.com.  I just tried ANAME so we'll see how that goes

Comment: Well, looks like ANAME worked actually

Comment: That's good :-). If you don't mind I will provide an answer. I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Resolution of `example.com` did not work because the DNS host (name.com) was set to resolve only `www.example.com` into CloudFront distro url.

The **solution** was to add `ANAME` record to point `example.com` into CloudFront distro url.